# replace $ with \$; knitr chunk options: echo=TRUE, results='markup;$=\\$'

Tags: r, knitr, pdflatex

I am trying to print R code within a Latex document using knitr.

I have the following simple code:

```
  \begin{frame}{Plot Code}
  <<plotcode,eval=FALSE,echo=TRUE,results='markup;$=\\$'>>=
```

... simple lm from randomly drawn data ...

```
  yhat.fit <- yhat$fit[,"fit"]
```

... more simple code ...

```
 \end{frame}
```

This will run, BUT, there is no replacement of the $ sign. Instead, I get math mode for 
fit[,"fit"] in the slide (along with "missing $ inserted" errors from pdflatex compilation.

I would rather not have math mode; instead I would like to see the $ sign, as that is integral to the R code.

As my workaround, I have replaced `$` with `\$` in my resulting `.tex` file, but I am hoping someone can fix my seemingly simple problem. I presume I am not specifying the markup and character structure correctly in the options, but I have tried a large number of variations with no success.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand what `results='markup;$=\\$'` really means. The [`results` option](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) does not take such a value; at the moment, it only accepts `markup`, `asis`, `hide`, and `hold`.

I do not see how `$` can be a problem in beamer, either. You probably forgot the `fragile` option. A minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\title{A Minimal Demo of knitr}
\author{Yihui Xie}

\maketitle

% very important to use option [fragile] for frames containing code output!

\begin{frame}[fragile]

You can test if \textbf{knitr} works with this minimal demo. OK, let's
get started with some boring random numbers:

<<boring-chunk>>=
fit = lm(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
fit$coefficients
print(sessionInfo(), locale = FALSE)
@

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: knitr with beamer]

Comment: I think I get the problem: if you use `results = 'asis'`, e.g. to display a nice table, then any trailing $ sign in the rest of the output for that particular chunk (R code etc.) will cause LaTeX to choke. The proposal is to add an optional post-processing filter, to sanitise the output with custom rules before LaTeX processes it. I don't think this is a good syntax for it, maybe a new argument `sanitise = list("$")` would be useful.

Comment: @baptiste I get it, but the OP did not seem to be using `results = 'asis'`. The value `'markup;$=\\$'` will be treated as `'markup'`, so I do not know how a dollar sign can escape from a verbatim environment.

Comment: Using [fragile] within the frame command solves the problem, but I was not sure how to trial sanitise=list($). I presume that goes back to something that might be used in the xtable environment?

Comment: I do not understand why you need an option like `sanitise=list($)`. As I said, the output is in a verbatim environment, then why bother escaping the special characters?